# Does Keras flow_from_directory iterate through every sample in a directory?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

From the Keras Preprocessing ImageDataGenerator module, the flow_from_directory method is used to create an Iterator from a directory containing sub-directories of images.  The Iterator runs indefinitely creating batches of images.  My question is, does it iterate through every sample per epoch?

For example, if I have 300 image total, and my batch size is 30, if I do 10 steps, does it iterate through every single sample once?  Or is each step an independent random sample from the entire dataset?  If we do iterate through every sample, what happens when I have a sample size not divisible by batch size (like 304 images)?  At step 11, does the iterator know to get the last 4 samples first, then get another 26 samples from the whole dataset?

Comment: Have you found answer? Because as I see now if batch_size is small and steps_per_epoch is also small and there is a lot of samples in directory, it doesn't train properly. I think it does not iterate over every sample in epoch.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand from the lines of code here https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/ and there https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/image.py, yes it iterates through all samples, and stops when `number_batches >= len(x_train) / batch_size`. It does that for each epoch, but the batches might be different for each epoch if `shuffle = True`.